# Brownian motion expected value of $W(1)$.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expected-value

I know that if $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion on the interval $[0,t]$, then
$$\mathbb{E}[W(t)]=0$$
but why $$\mathbb{E}[W(1)]=0?$$
Lets say that $W(1)=a$, then why we do not have 
$$\mathbb{E}[W(1)]=\mathbb{E}[a]=a?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$W(1)$ is a random variable and you cannot just suppose that it is equal to $a$. In fact, you know its distribution. If $W$ is a standard Brownian motion then $W(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$ for every $t$. In particular, $W(1) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ which is why $\mathbb{E}[W(1)] = 0$.